# How do I hide the increment insert of the record added to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-insert

**Table A**:

```
ID     NAME     SURNAME     BRANCH    
------------------------------------
1      Alma     Amelie       D         
5      Brisa    Broke        C
```

**Table B**:

```
ID     NAME     SURNAME     BRANCH    Count
-------------------------------------------
```

**New table B**:

```
ID     NAME     SURNAME     BRANCH    Count
-------------------------------------------
1      Alma     Amelie       D         1 
5      Brisa    Broke        C         1
```

I added table b to table a. I want the table to have a count of 1.

For example get count 2 when I want to make the second insert into the table. Get count 3 when I want to make the third insert into the table. I would like to define a variable from the master database and increase it as max + 1.

How can I do it? I moved the table, but I could not count. How can I do.

```
public void InsertTable()
{
    "INSERT INTO" + tbl_B + "select ID,NAME,SURNAME,COUNT" + "FROM" TBL_A ;
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Can you not define Count as an auto-increment field?

Comment: Could not define the automatic increase.No auto increment.Because the whole girth should be the same number.ıf 1 is 1. If 2 is 2. I need to define.

Comment: But tbl_a does not have a count.

Comment: tbl_A Does not count.Holding number tbl_ b.When the insert is incremented in table b, count is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

I write sql code, then all you need is just calling that in your C# code.
frist run this in sql server on your databse

```
create proc checktableB
(
@id int
)
as

if  EXISTS ( select ID,NAME,SURNAME,COUNT(*)as count  FROM TBL_A where ID=@id)

begin 
declare @I int;
set @I=(select COUNT(*) from tbl_A group by ID,NAME,SURNAME having ID=@id)+1

update tbl_B set COUNT=@I where ID=@id 
end
else 
begin 
INSERT INTO tbl_B select ID,NAME,SURNAME,1 FROM TBL_A
end
GO
---===============================
```

Call this proc in your method in c#:

```
public void InsertTable(int _ID)
{
"exec  checktableB @id="_ID //(any new id you want to insert or check )
}
```

Comment: Hi.I'm already created tables. I'm just inserting the table from the table. I'm inserting the empty table into it. How do I do that in this case.

Comment: Sir ,what do you mean by empty table, my code, first check that if your table by that id is fill and return data, then if exist ,update table b by new count else its insert new row..

Comment: For example; table was inserted 2 times at separate times. 2 will be count.
50 values were added in the first insert.5 Let the value of the value of 1 be 1 and all 1 get the number 1. 2 if all 2 is added.I will try.Thank you

Comment: yes its check if table is going to insert for 2nd time then its update table b count and set it to, plz if you find it useful vote it, thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
"INSERT INTO" + tbl_B + "select ID,NAME,SURNAME,(select max(COUNT)+1 from tbl_a)" + "FROM" TBL_A ;
```

But it won't work with multiple simultaneous inserts. For that you should create a sequence if your db allows them. You will get gaps but a unique, sequential count.